# Alternativa para criar um método novo num objeto String?

Tags: java, string, refatoração

Estou com a seguinte situação: tenho um arquivo txt de posições definidas (tipo CSV, CNAB, etc) para processar e extrair valores. Para fins de entendimento, segue o código que fiz e está funcionando perfeitamente:

```
public class Extract {

    final int[] CPF = new int[]{0, 10};
    final int[] NOME = new int[]{15, 45};

    public static void main(String args[]) {

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\cnab.txt");        
      String line;

      while ((line = fis.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(getValue(line, CPF));
          System.out.println(getValue(line, NOME)); 
      }
    }

    private String getValue(String line, int[] slice) {
        return line.substring(slice[0], slice[1]);
    }
 }
```

Até aí ok, mas eu gostaria de algo mais legível, elegante, tal como:

```
System.out.println(line.getValue(CPF));
```

Mas todos sabemos que String é *final*. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Troque a linguagem para C# e seja feliz :) Fora isto, não é possível, mas também muda muito pouco. Ainda bem que `String` é final, caso contrário as pessoas fariam atrocidades como fazem com a maioria das classes que não são.

Comment: Mesmo que você venha a usar C#, usar *Extension Methods* aqui seria uma grande gambiarra. Imagine uma String, um dos objetos mais coesos da linguagem, com um método *string.getValue(int[])*! A definição de uma classe nova é melhor solução.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Por que você não deve fazer isso

Alterar uma classe fundamental da linguagem (seja ela qual for) para implementar um simples requisito como este é um grande erro.

A linguagem Java, propositalmente, impede por questões de segurança que os tipos básicos como String e Integer sejam modificados ou estendidos com herança. Tais classes são declaradas com o modificador `final`.

Um dos grandes perigos disso é em relação à organização. Programadores começariam a fazer diversas modificações na linguagem, incluiriam bibliotecas que fariam outras modificações e o código acabaria uma grande bagunça.

Outro problema é em questão de desempenho. Sistemas grandes acabariam com muita sobrecarga de métodos adicionais e subclasses onde simplesmente não é necessário.

Já imaginou se cada programador tentasse modificar a classe `String` para atender às suas necessidades imediatas?

## Faça OO direito

Herança ou alteração de classes existentes **não** é a melhor solução do ponto de vista de *design* orientado a objetos para situações como esta.

Neste caso, você pode simplesmente encapsular a linha em um novo objeto contendo o método que você precisa.

Exemplo:

```
public class LinhaArquivo {
    private String linha;
    public LinhaArquivo(String linha) { 
        this.linha = linha;
    }
    public String getValue(int[] slice) {
        return linha.substring(slice[0], slice[1]);
    }
}
```

Então você poderia alterar o seu código da seguinte forma:

```
public class Extract {

    final int[] CPF = new int[]{0, 10};
    final int[] NOME = new int[]{15, 45};

    public static void main(String args[]) {

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\cnab.txt");        
      String line;

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          LinhaArquivo linha = new LinhaArquivo(line);
          System.out.println(linha.getValue(CPF));
          System.out.println(linha.getValue(NOME)); 
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: utluiz, talvez eu não tenha me expressado direito, sei porque String é final, quais as implicações e que, obviamente, não é permitido. Eu apenas queria uma solução elegante de maneira que o próprio objeto (a linha do arquivo txt) possuísse um método que extraísse de si mesmo um determinado valor a partir de um argumento passado como parâmetro.

Comment: Mágico. Muito bom. @dellasavia, nesta resposta você tem exatamente o que descreveu: *"o próprio objeto (a linha do arquivo txt) possui um método que extrai de si mesmo um determinado valor a partir de um argumento passado como parâmetro"*. Uma string é uma string, uma linha é uma linha. Não faz sentido "especializar" (herdar ou estender) uma string em linha. O utluiz definiu um objeto linha que **usa** uma string - isso é belo.

Answer (score 6):

Se as posições são estáticas, crie um enum

```
public enum ArchiveEnum {

NOME(0, 5),
CPF(6, 20);
private Integer minAge;
private Integer maxAge;

private ArchiveEnum(Integer minAge, Integer maxAge) {
    this.minAge = minAge;
    this.maxAge = maxAge;
}

public Integer getMinAge() {
    return minAge;
}

public void setMinAge(Integer minAge) {
    this.minAge = minAge;
}

public Integer getMaxAge() {
    return maxAge;
}

public void setMaxAge(Integer maxAge) {
    this.maxAge = maxAge;
}
}
```

E no seu método, passe o tipo do ENUM

```
public String getCampo(ArchiveEnum enumValue) {
    String archive = "TIAGO,111.111.111-11"; // Suposição de linha do arquivo
    return archive.subString(enumValue.getMinAge(), enumValue.getMaxAge()).toString();
}
```

Comment: Bevilaqua, creio ser esta a solução mais elegante, vou considerar sua resposta correta, mas eu criaria um método dentro do ENUM chamado `public String extractFrom(String line)` que extrairia o conteúdo do String baseado nas coordenadas definidas no construtor de cada ENUM e, na minha classe principal, bastaria chamar `System.out.println(ArchiveEnum.NOME.extractFrom(line));`.